# Rotate Object around origin as it faces origin in OpenGL with GLM?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation, glm-math

I'm trying to make a simple animation where an object rotates around the world origin in OpenGL using glm lib. My ideia is:

- Send object to origin
- Rotate it
- Send back to original position
- Make it look at what I want

Here's my implementation:

```
// Rotates object around point p
void rotate_about(float deltaTime, glm::vec3 p, bool ended) {

    glm::vec3 axis = glm::vec3(0,1,0); //rotation axis
    glm::mat4 scale_m = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(scale, scale, scale)); //scale matrix
    glm::mat4 rotation = getMatrix(Right, Up, Front, Position); //builds rotation matrix

    rotation = glm::translate(rotation, p - Position );
    rotation = glm::rotate(rotation, ROTATION_SPEED * deltaTime, axis);
    rotation = glm::translate(rotation, Position - p );

    Matrix = rotation * scale_m;

    //look at point P
    Front = glm::normalize(p - start_Position);
    Right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(WorldUp, Front));
    Up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Right, Front));

    if (ended == true) { //if last iteration of my animation: saves position
        Position.x = Matrix[3][0];
        Position.y = Matrix[3][1];
        Position.z = Matrix[3][2];  
    }
}
```

getMatrix() simply returns a 4x4 matrix as:

```
| Right.x Right.y Right.z |
| Up.x    Up.y    Up.z    |
| Front.x Front.y Front.z |
| Pos.x   Pos.y   Pos.z   |
```

I'm using this image as reference:

[image]

As it is my model simply disappears when I start the animation. If I remove lines bellow `"//look at point P"` it rotates around the origin, but twitches every time my animation restarts. I'm guessing I'm losing or mixing informations I shouldn't somewhere.
 How can I store my models Front/Right/Up information so I can rebuild its matrix from scratch?

**First edit**, this is the effect I'm having when I don't try to make my model look at the point P, in this case the origin. When I do try my model disappears. How can I make it look at where I want, and how can I get my models new Front/Right/Up vectors after I finish rotating it?

[image: Run example]

[This](https://pastebin.com/T9zsHTuH) is the code I ran in the gif above

Comment: First rotate around the exterior axis (MR1 matrix). Then translate the model (MT).Then rotate around its self vertical axis (MR2). The composed movement is achieved by MFInal = MR2 x MT x MR1. The order of matrices mulptipicatioin matters.

Comment: And that will make my model face the point? If so, what info should I be keeping after the animation, so I can put it in position for another rotation (continuing from where it stopped) ?

Comment: After exterior rotation with `angleE` you can know where the center of you model is, a simple `positionNew= matrix x positionOld` multiplication. With this new position and `angleE` you can calculate the angle to apply to the self rotation. Just store position and current self-angle for the next movement.

Comment: With that approach I'd have to store a self-angle for each axis (x,y,z) and then create 3 rotation matrices?

Comment: @MatheusIanzer In an [Right-handed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) system it has to be [Right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Front, WorldUp));]`. But it is still unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Rabbid76 my goal is for the cyborg to orbit around a center point as it faces the point, doing so smoothly. Or at least don't "twitch" every time the animation restarts like it is doing in the gif I posted.

Answer (score 3):

Operations like [`glm::translate()`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00668.html#ga1a4ecc4ad82652b8fb14dcb087879284) or [`glm::roate()`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00668.html#gaee9e865eaa9776370996da2940873fd4) build a matrix by its parameters and multiply the input matrix by the new matrix

This means that

```
rotation = glm::translate(rotation, Position - p );
```

can be expressed as (pseudo code):

```
rotation = rotation * translation(Position - p);
```

Note, that the matrix multiplication has to be "read" from the left to the right. (See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations))

The operation `translate * rotate` causes a rotation around the origin of the object:

[image]

The operation `rotate * translate` causes a rotation around the origin of the world:

[image]

The matrix `glm::mat4 rotation` (in the code of your question) is the current model matrix of your object.
It contains the position (**translation**) and the orientation of the object.
You want to rotate the object around the origin of the world.

To do so you have to create a matrix which contains the new rotation

```
glm::mat4 new_rot = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), ROTATION_SPEED * deltaTime, axis);
```

Then you can calculate the final matrix as follows:

```
Matrix = new_rot * rotation * scale_m;
```

---

If you want to rotate an object around the a point `p` and the object should always face a point `p`, then all you need is the position of the object (`start_position`) and the rotation axis.
In your case the rotation axis is the up vector of the world.

```
glm::vec3 WorldUp( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
glm::vec3 start_position = ...;
float scale = ...;
glm::vec3 p = ...;
```

Calculate the rotation matrix and the new (rotated) position

```
glm::mat4 rotate    = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), ROTATION_SPEED * deltaTime, WorldUp);
glm::vec4 pos_rot_h = rotate * glm::vec4( start_position - p, 1.0f );
glm::vec3 pos_rot   = glm::vec3( pos_rot_h ) + p;
```

Calculate the direction in which the object should "look"

```
glm::vec3 Front    = glm::normalize(p - pos_rot);
```

You can use your function `getMatrix` to setup the current orientation matrix of the object:

```
glm::vec3 Right    = glm::normalize(glm::cross(WorldUp, Front));
glm::mat4 pos_look = getMatrix(Right, WorldUp, Front, pos_rot);
```

Calculate the model matrix:

```
glm::mat4 scale_m = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(scale));
Matrix = pos_look * scale_m;
```

The final code may look like this:

```
glm::mat4 getMatrix(const glm::vec3 &X, const glm::vec3 &Y, const glm::vec3 &Z, const glm::vec3 &T)
{
    return glm::mat4(
        glm::vec4( X, 0.0f ),
        glm::vec4( Y, 0.0f ),
        glm::vec4( Z, 0.0f ),
        glm::vec4( T, 1.0f ) );
}

void rotate_about(float deltaTime, glm::vec3 p, bool ended) {

    glm::mat4 rotate    = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), ROTATION_SPEED * deltaTime, WorldUp);
    glm::vec4 pos_rot_h = rotate * glm::vec4( start_position - p, 1.0f );
    glm::vec3 pos_rot   = glm::vec3( pos_rot_h ) + p;

    glm::vec3 Front    = glm::normalize(p - pos_rot);
    glm::vec3 Right    = glm::normalize(glm::cross(WorldUp, Front));
    glm::mat4 pos_look = getMatrix(Right, WorldUp, Front, pos_rot);

    glm::mat4 scale_m = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(scale));
    Matrix = pos_look * scale_m;

    if ( ended == true )
        Position = glm::vec3(Matrix[3]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Rabbid76. But I'm getting the same behaviour with your suggestion. My main problem here is making my model look at where I want as it rotates around a point. I editted my question so to make it clearer, I'd be glad if you could take a look at it.

Comment: @MatheusIanzer I extended the answer

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was in this part:

```
rotation = glm::translate(rotation, p - Position ); 
rotation = glm::rotate(rotation, ROTATION_SPEED * deltaTime, axis);
rotation = glm::translate(rotation, Position - p );


if (ended == true) { //if last iteration of my animation: saves position
    Position.x = Matrix[3][0];
    Position.y = Matrix[3][1];
    Position.z = Matrix[3][2];  
}
```

Note that I was using the distance between world origin and model as the radius of the translation. However, after the animation ends I update the models Position, which changes the result of `p - Position`, i.e, the orbit radius. When this happen the model "twitches", because it lost rotation information.

I solved it by using a different variable for the orbit radius, and applying the translation on the `z-axis` of the model. When the translation is applied on the x-axis, the model - which faces the camera initially - will end up **sideways** to the origin. However, applying the translation on the z-axis will end up with the model either facing or backwards to the origin, depending on the signal.